# How to preserve variable in django model manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In django model manager if multiple methods have the same parameter, do I have to pass them every time I call the method?

```
class MyManager(model.Manager):
    def show(self,request,A,B)
        pass

    def hide(self,request,A,B,C)
        pass
```

You can see the `request` `A` `B` are same parameter,
can I have something like this:

```
 class MyManager(model.Manager):
    def __init__(self,request,A,B):
        self.request = request
        self.A= A
        self.B= B

    def show(self)
        pass

    def hide(self,C)
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

`__init__()` is called when the associated Model class is built at server startup time. Do you know what those variables are at sever startup? Are they going to stay constant over the life of the server's runtime?

If the answer to those two questions is yes, then go ahead and use this solution.

Otherwise you will need to pass them every time.